# Насколько языки разметки являются программированием?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Меня интересуют ответы на вот такие простые вопросы.

- HTML/CSS — это языки программирования?
- Когда мы верстаем сайт на HTML и CSS, то это можно назвать программированием?
- Можно ли назвать скриптерами тех, кто программирует на PHP? Или кто вообще такие скриптеры?

Comment: Это совершенно нетехнические вопросы, и на них нет однозначного ответа. Не стоит спрашивать такое на этом сайте.

Comment: @PashaPash, "и на них нет однозначного ответа" - поэтому как раз спрашивать и стоит.

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда нужно отвечать развернутыми ответами. а не "да, да, нет, нет" как ниже

Comment: @PashaPash, согласен. Я ещё дополню ответ. Просто решил быстро ответить, пока не закрыли вопрос.

Comment: @PashaPash, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy суть ответа все равно "возможно, возможно, возможно".

Comment: @PashaPash, а ты хочешь увидеть ответ "да, да, нет"? У меня такой смысл, но отрицать спорность ответов на эти вопросы бессмысленно.

Comment: @Qwertiy я вообще не хочу видеть ответы. imho, между отсутствием ответов, и ответом "хз" лучше выбрать первое.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26816/discussion-between-pashapash-and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 4):

Ответы на ваши вопросы в общем то относятся к области определения или наоборот мироощущения. Скажем, Wikipedia относит HTML к программированию - источник конечно сомнительный (прямо скажем), но точка зрения имеет право на жизнь и я уверен, что мильоны верстальщиков согласятся с этим.

С другой стороны, всякий уважающий себя Java/C/C++/C# программер с уверенностью скажет, что HTML/CSS это вообще не язык программирования. Точка зрения, которая имеет право на жизнь.

По поводу скриптов/скриптирования/скриптеров и проч. Скриптирование это по определению некое программирование, в котором программа выполняется с своей среде, причем интерпретируется (без этапа компиляции). Типичные примеры: Python/bash и вообще все shell'ы

Одной из основных задач скриптирования является написание связки между различными программными компонентами.

Скажем, есть программа написанная на Fortrane, которая принимает данные в виде текстового файла и выкидывает результат обратно в текстовый файл. Исходные данные лежат в SQL, а результат надо представить в виде Excel графика - типичная задача скриптера.

Скриптирование конечно же программирование, но вспомогательное программирование - не более того.

Comment: HTML и CSS — это языки *разметки*, ибо неполнота по Тьюрингу. А то получается, что то же Markdown тоже язык программирования. Так что Википедия, ммм... вводит в заблуждение.

Answer (score 3):

> html/css это языки программирования?

Спорно. Я допускаю, что их можно назвать языками программирования, однако, они не в полной мере ими являются.

Изначально html был именно языком разметки, однако, по мере его развития, в сочетании с css он обладает всё большими возможностями. В том числе, можно создавать интерактивные страницы полностью без использования скриптов.

Что касается декларативности, она не может противопоставляться понятию языка прграммирования. Например, пролог является декларативным.

[Танцующий Бендер на CSS3](http://habrahabr.ru/post/198646/) и [демо](http://liveweave.com/GoGhKy).

> Когда мы верстаем сайт на html и css, то это можно назвать программированием?

Скорее всего, да.

Хотя, тут есть два варианта. Либо дизайнер, либо разработчик. В первом случае я подразумеваю создание чисто визуального оформления, без полного понимания html и css. Хотя, большинство дизайнеров всё же разбираются в этом. Тут скорее различие в целях - создать оформление и создать работающий сайт. Второе - программирование, а первое - нет.

> Можно ли назвать скриптерами тех, кто программирует на PHP? Или кто вообще такие скриптери?

Впервые встречаю понятие "скриптеры". Похоже, что это те, кто пишут вспомогательные скрипты. Так что, нет. Php - это точно программирование. Хотя, если там какие-то мелкие приписки к CMS, то, с некоторой натяжкой, можно.

Вообще, мне кажется, следует избегать этого названия, поскольку в случае нормальной разработки (и даже посредственной разработки) оно имеет негативную окраску. По крайней мере, у меня от него создаётся такое впечатление.

Comment: "можно назвать языками программирования" - и я даже готов поспорить. Язык программирования должен реализовать некий алгоритм, соответственно должен иметь возможность реализовать все основные алгоритмические конструкции. Покажете как сделать цикл на HTML или CSS - соглашусь, что это языки программирования.

Comment: @tutankhamun, покажи, как сделать цикл в прологе.

Comment: Ну почти уел :) Только я не силен в Прологе и что-то подсказывает мне что там это делается через рекурентный вызов, то есть по сути алгоритмическая конструкция реализуема

Answer (score -2):

1. Нет, это декларативные (описательные) языки. Мы только описываем результат.
2. Нет.
3. Это не очень понятный термин, но, видимо, да. Другое дело, что под скриптерами наверняка подразумеваются люди с не самой большой квалификацией, и нормальные программисты вряд ли к ним относятся.

Comment: т.е. если язык не императивный - то он уже не ЯП? Хаскель не ЯП? или пролог тоже не ЯП?

Comment: @PashaPash я когда-нибудь форкну Копателя и превращу его в Докопателя. Вы прекрасно понимаете, почему я не стал уходить в детали.

Comment: Не понимаю какой смысл вообще отвечать на такой вопрос и при этом не уходить в детали. ТС же наверное хочет обоснованного ответа. [В википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), например, HTML упоминается в подразделе Математически обоснованные языки программирования (вместе с хаскелем и прочей функциональщиной). Но ваше "нет" это, естественно, перевешивает.

Comment: @PashaPash потому что сама формулировка вопроса подразумевает, что человеку нужен немного иной ответ.

Comment: Ответ совершенно неверный. Тут даже и рассуждать нечего, имхо.